# X-Mirror on weight paint doesn't work

Tags: mirror

I've heard that x-mirror option is supposed to mirror the weight paint that I do on one side to the other. But it isn't working with my mesh for some reason, it still only paints on side at a time. Any help why?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1neePPk9PlKjhpp8AIbUOF94m1KHws7hX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

The mesh is not a perfect mirror so it can't find the opposite side. You could try to use the "Topology mirror" option and see it that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I presume its because of the book item on his back. Could it also be because the bones on the right side shoulder and arms are slightly rotated compared to the ones on the left? That's another problem I had when trying to duplicate to the other side

Comment: The bone rotation is probably unrelated but when rigging you need to take control over the bone roll and not leave that to chance. Use Recalculate Roll and make sure that your rotational axises match up. It will be horrible to animate if you don't.

Comment: You should also make sure that your origin is in the right position. Don't assume that centre of weight will get it right. The mesh object shouldn't have any scaling done to it when rigging.

Comment: Thank you for the help again. I found that the easier solution was to right click on all my left side selected bones, right click, then symmetrize. Must be a new option in 2.8, I don't remember it being in 2.79. However, no we're back to square 1. I removed the object that was making my mesh uneven, and everything I've worked on on the mesh was done in mirror, then applied. However I'm still not getting the proper x-mirror results.